# Add custom header to subscription of microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to subscribe to notification as described in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0

My notification URL cannot be accessed, unless a bearer token in the header is also sent.

How can I add custom header on the subscription of notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported today. The only thing that Microsoft graph can pass back to your notification URL when validating and/or delivering notifications are query string parameters. The notification URL must be publicly accessible with anonymous access. If you'd like to request such a feature, you can [create an idea on uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com).